# Tensorflow session and graph within class

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to make a class that contains a tensorflow model, along with a predict routine. Specifically it's for the Universal Sentence Encoder, through the `tfHub` module.

The code looks like:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

class TextModel():
    def __init__(self)
        self.tfhub_link = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/3"

        # Configure Tensorflow Session
        self.tf_config = tf.ConfigProto()
        self.tf_config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
        self.tf_config.log_device_placement = False
        self.tf_config.intra_op_parallelism_threads=1
        self.tf_config.inter_op_parallelism_threads=1
        tf_graph = tf.Graph()

        with tf_graph.as_default():
            tf_sess = tf.Session(graph=tf_graph,config=self.tf_config)
            with tf_sess.as_default():
                self.tf_sess = tf_sess
                self.tf_graph = tf_graph
                self.model = hub.Module(self.tfhub_link)
                self.tf_sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
                self.tf_sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())

        #Make a dummy prediction to initalize everything in tensorflow
        init_txt = "Hey, how are you feeling?"
        logger.info('Test Prediction: {0}'.format(str(self.model_predict(init_txt))))

    def model_predict(self,txt):
        return self.tf_sess.run(self.model(txt))
```

The problem is that when I run `model_predict`, I get:

`RuntimeError: Module must be applied in the graph it was instantiated for.`

This makes no sense to me, as I clearly pass the graph to the session. I've noticed that if I do:

```
def model_predict(self,txt):
    with self.tf_graph.as_default():
        return self.tf_sess.run(self.model(txt))
```

then everything works, but I think now the graph is being recreated every single time, as the speed is really slow.